# Discord.js Addin reaction to bot message

Tags: discord.js

I want reactions to be added to the bot in the message but not to me. Someone can help me?

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!event') {
    if (msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Event Manager")) {
        msg.channel.send('Внимание вопрос!\nХотите ли вы ивент?')
        .then(function (message) {
          msg.react('⭕');
          msg.react('❌');
        }).catch(function() {
       });
    }
    else {
      msg.channel.send("У вас нету прав на выполнение данного действия.")
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    client.on('message', async msg => {
      if(msg.content === '!event') {
        if(msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Event Manager")) {
            const message = await msg.channel.send('Внимание вопрос!\nХотите ли вы ивент?');
            await message.react('⭕');
            await message.react('❌');
        }else{
          msg.channel.send("У вас нету прав на выполнение данного действия.");
        }
      } 
    });
```

You should use async function which makes your code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!event') {
    if (msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Event Manager")) {
        msg.channel.send('Внимание вопрос!\nХотите ли вы ивент?')
        .then(function (message) {
          message.react('⭕');
          message.react('❌');
        }).catch(function() {
       });
    }
    else {
      msg.channel.send("У вас нету прав на выполнение данного действия.")
    }
  } 
});
```

Just change from `msg` to `message` because you passing the message with then